# portability Variance problem

Tags: probability, random-variable

**Problem:**

Consider the attached probability distribution. Calculate 
$$\mathrm{Var}[ \ln(2X+3) ]$$ where $\ln(\cdot )$ is the natural logarithm.

```
x       1   3   5   
p(X=x) 0.2 0.6  0.2
```

I am stuck with what to do with $\ln$ in the Var equation. What I have done so far, if I am right:

$$\mathbb E[X] = 3, \mathbb E[X^2] = 10.6, \mathrm{Var}[X] = 1.6$$

and

$$\mathrm{Var}(aX+b) = a^2 \mathrm{Var}(X)$$

given me $2^2(1.6) = 6.4$ Were does the $\ln$ fit into all of this?

Comment: Unfortunately your calculations are not useful at all. You need to be calculating $E[\ln(2X+3)]$ and $E[\ln^2(2X+3)]$.

Comment: Hint: add another row to your table giving the values of $\log(2X+3) = \log(5), \log(9), \log(13).$  What do you mean by "portability" in the title?

Comment: The problem is i dont understand the question or how to work it out. i took the ln(6.4) and it give one of the answers but i am assuming that it was a pit fall. any help would be appericated thx.

Comment: You showed us how you work out the expectation and variance of a random variable.  That's all this question asks you to do, but using different numbers.  The formulas don't change.

Comment: i dont know how to deal with the ln part sorry if that sounds silly or not

Comment: LOTUS technique comes handy in such scenarios. It is simple and applicable in such questions.
It helps to find E( g(x) ) in terms of E(x).